# Taquito default entrypoint not found

Tags: smart-contracts, smartpy, dapps, taquito

I have deployed a [smart contract](https://better-call.dev/carthage/KT1DNG6HZpmdRzKjQrachmQWtSHSYkBHeKiK/operations) on carthagenet.

The contract only has a single entry point.

Taquito is not able to find that single entry point. I tried both default and root methods and it doesn't work.

```
const op = await contract.methods.default(contractAddress).send()
const op = await contract.methods.root(contractAddress).send()
```

Error message

```
contract.methods.default is not a function
contract.methods.root is not a function
```

Comment: The contract you point to takes a single parameter of type address. Thus, as you write, it only has the default entrypoint. It might be that taquito does not recognize the default entry point as an entrypoint. After talking with the taquito authors, seems like you should try contract.methods.main(contractAddress).send(). In otherwords, main = default in taquito.

Comment: It works. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contract you point to takes a single parameter of type `address`. Thus, as you write, it only has the [default entrypoint](http://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html#the-default-entrypoint). In taquito, the main entry point can be call through `contract.methods.main`. So your call should be:

```
contract.methods.main(contractAddress).send()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the name `main` was a bit confusing, it was renamed from `main` to `default` in the latest version of Taquito [(version v7.0.0-beta)](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/version/).

This is a breaking change for implementations that use the `main` method for calling the default entrypoint of a contract.

Before version 7:

```
contract.methods.main(contractAddress).send()
```

Since version 7:

```
contract.methods.default(contractAddress).send()
```

More details can be found on the [upgrading guide of Taquito](https://tezostaquito.io/docs/v7_breaking_changes).